# OFFSET vs. ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: postgresql

As we know, Postgresql's OFFSET requires that it scan through all the rows up until the point it gets to where you requested, which makes it kind of useless for pagination through huge result sets, getting slower and slower as the OFFSET goes up.

PG 8.4 now supports window functions.   Instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY somecol LIMIT 10 OFFSET 500
```

You can say:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY somecol ASC) AS rownum FROM table) AS foo
WHERE rownum > 500 AND rownum <= 510
```

Does the latter approach help us at all ?   Or do we have to keep using identifying columns and temp tables for large pagination ?

Comment: Why would a CURSOR not be an option? It's realy fast on a large resultset and it doesn't harm you nor your code. Works fine in PHP. A cursor works even better in other types of applications, that's true but don't worry about a webapp and don't limit yourself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've constructed a test which compares OFFSET, cursors, and ROW_NUMBER().   My impression of ROW_NUMBER(), that it would be consistent in speed regardless of where you are in the result set, is correct.  However, that speed is dramatically slower than either OFFSET or CURSOR, which, as was also my impression, are pretty much the same in speed, both degrading in speed the further out to the end of the result you go.

Results:

```py
offset(100,100): 0.016359
scroll(100,100): 0.018393
rownum(100,100): 15.535614

offset(100,480000): 1.761800
scroll(100,480000): 1.781913
rownum(100,480000): 15.158601

offset(100,999900): 3.670898
scroll(100,999900): 3.664517
rownum(100,999900): 14.581068
```

The test script uses sqlalchemy to set up tables and 1000000 rows of test data.  It then uses a psycopg2 cursor to execute each SELECT statement and fetch results with the three different methods.

```py
from sqlalchemy import *

metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test', echo=True)

t1 = Table('t1', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('d1', String(50)),
    Column('d2', String(50)),
    Column('d3', String(50)),
    Column('d4', String(50)),
    Column('d5', String(50))
)

if not engine.has_table('t1'):
    conn = engine.connect()
    t1.create(conn)
    
    # 1000000 rows
    for i in range(100):
        conn.execute(t1.insert(), [
            dict(
                ('d%d' % col, "data data data %d %d" % (col, (i * 10000) + j))
                for col in range(1, 6)
            ) for j in xrange(1, 10001)
        ])

import time

def timeit(fn, count, *args):
    now = time.time()
    for i in xrange(count):
        fn(*args)
    total = time.time() - now
    print "%s(%s): %f" % (fn.__name__, ",".join(repr(x) for x in args), total)
    
# this is a raw psycopg2 connection.
conn = engine.raw_connection()

def offset(limit, offset):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from t1 order by id limit %d offset %d" % (limit, offset))
    cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()

def rownum(limit, offset):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from (select *, "
                    "row_number() over (order by id asc) as rownum from t1) as foo "
                    "where rownum>=%d and rownum<%d" % (offset, limit + offset))
    cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()

def scroll(limit, offset):
    cursor = conn.cursor('foo')
    cursor.execute("select * from t1 order by id")
    cursor.scroll(offset)
    cursor.fetchmany(limit)
    cursor.close()

print 

timeit(offset, 10, 100, 100)
timeit(scroll, 10, 100, 100)
timeit(rownum, 10, 100, 100)

print 

timeit(offset, 10, 100, 480000)
timeit(scroll, 10, 100, 480000)
timeit(rownum, 10, 100, 480000)

print 
    
timeit(offset, 10, 100, 999900)
timeit(scroll, 10, 100, 999900)
timeit(rownum, 10, 100, 999900)
```

Comment: Did you enable server_side_cursors? If not, the above code didn't create a database cursor, the thing you were looking for. http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/dialects/postgres.html?highlight=cursor

Comment: psycopg2 server side cursors are invoked when you call the cursor with a name, as in http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors .   If you remove the name argument from the call to cursor(), the "scroll" function above takes about ten seconds per call - this because psycopg2 fully loads the result set if you don't turn on server side cursors and in the above case it pulls 1M rows over the wire.

Comment: What if we need to get the total number of rows along side? In my mind that's where row over makes sense. You select all without limit adding the row number and total count as additional columns with cte and then use where row number is between.  Or is limit offset still better then?

Answer (score 4):

Use a [CURSOR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-declare.html) for a large resultset, will be much faster. For small result sets the LIMIT OFFSET construction works fine, but it has it's limits.

ROW_NUMBER is a nice thing, but not for pagination. You end up with bad performance because of sequential scan's.

Comment: Do cursors won't work well when you're doing pagination?  Don't they disappear when the connection ends?

Comment: mm yeah this is for a webapp, so cursors aren't an option.

Comment: Yes, a CURSOR does dissappear after your connection ends and that's fine. It's still much much faster then any other solution. A query using LIMIT OFFSET or ROW_NUMBER also dissappears. I have no idea why a CURSOR can't be used in a webapp, it works great over here. Start testing and see how much you will gain. (or loose)