# Row number of a record in a query

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I need to find the page number of a record in a query.  I have offset and limit, but will also need the row number to calculate this.

Given a query object, and a record ID, how could I find the row number?

row number should be relative to the query table.  limit and offset will be applied afterwards.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: What's a "page number"? (I know what it is, I'm offering it as a way for you to think how you think this is an answerable question)

Comment: page number as relative to pagination client-side.  not really relevant to the answer i am seeking, but figured I'd give some background.

Comment: and is row number relative to the table size or the page size etc... etc.. - you need to be more specific with examples

Comment: (I'm assuming here you have a SQL query.) Wouldn't you just perform your unpaged query as a subselect, complete with record number, and then calculate your page number based on that single record's data (specifically record number) and your page size? ... um, nevermind. I just now saw your tag for SQL Alchemy. My bad. :-)

Comment: row number is relative to the query table.  offset/limit will be applied afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked long and hard, and after 6hrs found a solution.

I use Mysql so I believe the only way I can do this is with @ variables.

Here is how I implemented it into SQLAlchemy:

```
qry = ...
sel = select([qry.c.id, "@rownum := @rownum + 1 as rownumber"])
conn = sel.engine.connect()
conn.execute("SET @rownum:=0")
res = conn.execute(sel)
```

`@rownum` will increment with each row.  we can add more columns from `qry` on the 2nd line if we wanted to.  `res` is the final table with the `rownumber` column, where we can call `res.fetchall()` to return a list

Comment: if @rownum is established locally to a single MySQL connection then you'd to use an explicit Connection above (i.e. with engine.connect() as conn:), as executing from the engine() isn't guaranteed to use the same connection twice (plus concurrent access could grab that connection).

Comment: thanks for that explanation.  I find SQLALchemy docs a bit hard to learn from (it's very paragraph-ized), how did you learn it?

Comment: ah well... check my profile.   just got done arguing on the mailing list with a guy who wants it to be *more* paragraphs.   there's no pleasing everyone....

Answer (score 2):

It's a little awkward to get the "page number" of the record going backwards like that, usually a system that wants to bounce from the "detail" of a record back to the "paginated view of all of them" would just carry along the page number to the "detail" page.

But assuming you're working with a capable database you can get row numbers out of an arbitrary SELECT statement using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html), which you can get with a DB like Postgresql, SQL Server or Oracle (notably not MySQL or SQLite).

Using PG we can start with some data:

```
test=> create table data(id SERIAL primary key, value varchar(20));
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "data_id_seq" for serial column "data.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "data_pkey" for table "data"
CREATE TABLE
test=> insert into data (value) values ('d1'), ('d2'), ('d3'), ('d4'), ('d5'), ('d6'), ('d7'), ('d8'), ('d9'), ('d10'), ('d11'), ('d12'), ('d13'), ('d14'), ('d15'), ('d16');
INSERT 0 16
```

we can then select this data and get an integer row count using the `row_number()` window function:

```
test=> select value, row_number() over (order by id) as rownum from data;
 value | rownum 
-------+--------
 d1    |      1
 d2    |      2
 d3    |      3
 d4    |      4
 d5    |      5
 d6    |      6
 d7    |      7
 d8    |      8
 d9    |      9
 d10   |     10
 d11   |     11
 d12   |     12
 d13   |     13
 d14   |     14
 d15   |     15
 d16   |     16
(16 rows)
```

Applying the windowed data inside of a subquery, we can select slices of the result based on this count:

```
test=> select value from (select value, row_number() 
     > over (order by id) as rownum from data) as sub where rownum between 5 and 10;
 value 
-------
 d5
 d6
 d7
 d8
 d9
 d10
(6 rows)
```

So if you had the record "d14" and a page size of 5 you could do this:

```
test=> select (rownum - 1) / 5 from (select value, row_number() 
     > over (order by id) as rownum from data) as sub where value='d14';
 ?column? 
----------
        2
(1 row)
```

SQLAlchemy provides window functions via the [over()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over) method/function, so a SQLA query assuming a typical ORM mapping for this would look like:

```
subq = session.query(
            Data.value, 
            func.row_number().over(order_by=Data.id).label('rownum')
       ).subquery()
pagenum = session.query((subq.c.rownum - 1) / 5).\
       filter(subq.c.value == 'd14').scalar()
```

As far as using window functions vs. limit/offset for pagination, it's worth checking out the [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3125571/34549) I wrote over here comparing the performance of the various methods, as well as the [windowed range query](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/WindowedRangeQuery) recipe I sometimes use.

Comment: this would work perfectly but I am using MySQL, which I should have specified in my topic.  I apologize.  I have found a solution which I will post.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't mention it was MySQL or I wouldn't have been able to give a great tutorial on window functions :)

Comment: @zzzeek How about MySQL or SQLITE Database ? Is there any solutions on them?

Answer (score 0):

After a long searching, I found the following MySQL solution:

```
SELECT d.myRowSerial
FROM (
    SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS myRowSerial 
    FROM myTable, (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS nothingButSetInitialValue 
    WHERE 1=1 -- Optional: filter if required, otherwise, omit this line;
    ORDER BY AnyColumn -- Apply the order you like; 
) d
WHERE d.myColumn = 'Anything'; -- If you like to limit it to only
-- for any specific row(s), similar to the *MAIN query.
```

If you need the page number too, then just change the 1st line above like this:

```
SELECT d.myRowSerial, FLOOR((d.myRowSerial-1)/10) AS pageNumber
-- Say, 10 is per page;
```

You will have pageNumber==0 for page 1, and pageNumber=1 for page 2, .....