# To number a query result in the query statement with flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to give an ordering number to each line of a query, and I know the SQL statement in MySql environment.
With my testing database, the sql statement without order is:

```
SELECT `department`.`name` AS `department`, `staff`.`firstName` AS `firstName`, `staff`.`lastName` AS `lastName` FROM `department`,`staff` WHERE `staff`.`department_id`=`department`.`id`;
```

And its query result in MySql is:

[Query with no number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIIYc.png)

The related numbered sql statement of the above sql statement is :

```
SELECT (@i:=@i+1) AS `id`,`department`.`name` AS `department`, `staff`.`firstName` AS `firstName`, `staff`.`lastName` AS `lastName` FROM `department`,`staff`,(SELECT @i:=0) AS `tmp` WHERE `staff`.`department_id`=`department`.`id`;
```

And its query result in MySql is:

[Query with number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB4J0.png)

I also know the flask sqlalchemy statement in python for the first without number case can be:

```
qList=db.session.query(Department.name.label("department"),Staff.firstName.label("firstName"),Staff.lastName.label("lastName")).select_from(Department,Staff).filter(Staff.department_id==Department.id).all()
```

This will give me a list containing the above data.

But how can I write the `(SELECT @i:=0) AS`tmp`" and "(@i:=@i+1) AS`id part in flask sqlalchemy statement?

I use flask 1.0.2 ,flask_sqlalchemy 2.3.2 .

Comment: Something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698730/5781248 ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! According to your reference, because my database software is MySql, I cannot use row_number() function, so I use origin sql statement to set sql variable `db.session.execute("SET @i:=0;") `and add a query column `@i := @i + 1 AS id`, Then my problem solved!  @J.J.Hakala

Comment: It might be available in a new version, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/