# Why is row_number() faster than using offset?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

In experimenting somewhat with window functions in PostgreSQL 9.3, I came across a rather interesting case. In direct contradiction to answers on [OFFSET vs. ROW_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125571/offset-vs-row-number), I have found that window functions are actually *faster* than OFFSET.

Using offset, takes ~2500ms:

```
select part_no, description
from inventory
order by part_no
limit 1000 offset 400000
```

Using row_number(), takes ~450ms:

```
select *
from (select part_no, description, row_number() OVER () 
    from inventory
    order by part_no) AS ss
where row_number >= 400001
limit 1000
```

This (freshly analyzed) table has about 450,000 rows, and part_no is indexed. EXPLAIN indicates that an index scan is being performed in the row_number() case, and a sequential scan in the OFFSET case.

I've tried different combinations of OFFSET, row_number() with different offset sizes and indexed vs unindexed sort orders. All times are approximate averages of a couple runs (query times were generally very consistent.)

```
            -------indexed-------    ------unindexed------
offset by   OFFSET   row_number()    OFFSET   row_number()
==========================================================
400000      2500ms          450ms     500ms          650ms
40000         80ms           60ms     850ms          650ms
4000          30ms           30ms     390ms          650ms
```

I guess the real question here is; what is the query planner doing differently in these two cases, and how can I get it to make better choices (particularly in the large offset+indexed column case)?

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison is *not completely valid*. You need to use:

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY part_no)
```

to get equivalent results. And `ORDER BY` needs to move to the outer query. So:

```
SELECT part_no, description
FROM  (
   SELECT part_no, description, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY part_no) AS rn
   FROM   inventory) AS ss
WHERE  rn > 400000
ORDER  BY rn
LIMIT  1000;
```

Or:

```
SELECT part_no, description
FROM  (
   SELECT part_no, description, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY part_no) AS rn
   FROM   inventory) AS ss
WHERE  rn BETWEEN 400000 AND 401000
ORDER  BY rn;
```

Also, the comparison you are referring to is 4 years old, and the version of Postgres has not been declared. I assume you are testing with the latest 9.3? There have been many improvements over the last couple of years ...

Comment: I moved the ORDER BY into the OVER clause, which seems to have had little effect on the performance. Interestingly, adding the outer ORDER BY caused the query to run very slowly again (>5s) but doesn't appear to have changed the order of the results at all. It seems that the presence of the outer ORDER BY is causing the planner to show two sort steps where the former case elides both (though must one be implicit within the WindowAgg.