# Postgresql pagination

Tags: database, postgresql, pagination

I came to know that PostgreSQL pagination (using **LIMIT and OFFSET**) is damn slow, unfortunately, its very late to me to understand this, because one of my small web app project uses it as the DB and the development is almost over.

I have seen a few workarounds in SO and other sites, but all of them uses extra indexes and things like that. But it does not suit me because I will have to create many indexes (there are a few dozens of tables) for the tables and will also have to rewrite the queries. So my question is :

1. Is there a way I can avoid this without spending more time (creating those extra indexes and rewriting query, etc) ? I mean, a simple workaround ?
2. I have not felt this slow with MySQL (and I guess, so is Oracle), hence, will PostgreSQL people be improving that in future versions ? or won't they do it at all ? (If they have a plan, I would like to keep on with PostgreSQL, if not I would go for MySQL, because a typical web app/ERP will have a lot of pagination requirements, and it is not wise to do extra work for this basic need)

Comment: You can increase `work_mem` setting to allow for more in-memory sorting. But it is crucial on any database system to figure out which indexes would be beneficial and implementing them. No database will think for you - it's your job.

Comment: `work_mem` won´t help much for huge table, unless you set it to huge number, but then it will let to consume much memory for EVERY other sorting

Comment: More information is needed, like datamodel, query and the results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the slow and fast (!) queries involved. Pagination can be very fast, but a slow query will never be fast...

Comment: Check out this link: http://chrisdone.com/posts/postgresql-pagination

Answer (score 1):

pagination?.. if you mean `LIMIT OFFSET` it is quite fast. Comparing to `LIMIT WHERE ROWNUM` of Oracle, `LIMIT N,O` in mysql... Quite same in all aspects

So answers would be:

1. Without spending time - nothing will happen
2. Things are being improved in every version. They will do some.

[NB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125571/offset-vs-row-number)

Comment: LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10000000 means that postgres fetchs 10000000 rows and ignore them. As result everything is fine only until you use small offset.

Comment: good point. all three are same in regard of sequential reads.